# The error that I am seeing on the console: "NoSuchElementException" when testing out an website using selenium. I'm new at this. unable to key in pwd

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to select the password html element i.e,  tag... Even though i have tried using various find element methods provided by selenium to select it directly and indirectly and given proper values for the methods as well. still I'm unable to select the  tag for the password

````
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class demo {
    WebDriver driver;
 @BeforeTest
 public void Test1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("http://www.voot.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
 }
 @Test
 public void Test2() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MuiAvatar-root-136 MuiAvatar- 
                         colorDefault-137 withRouter-UserDropdownMenu--avatar- 
                          120']")).click();
        WebElement dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.className("withRouter- 
                    UserDropdownMenu--dropDownContent-124"));
        WebElement login = dropdownlist.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='MuiListItem-root- 
                              143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-151 
                          withRouter-UserDropdownMenu--ListItem-126']"));
        Thread.sleep(500);
        login.click();
        Thread.sleep(200);
    
        WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='User Sync']"));
        iframe.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='email- 
                      icon']|//img[@src='/images/icon_mail_purple.svg']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        try {
        WebElement emailprovide = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
        emailprovide.sendKeys("abc123@gmail.com",Keys.ENTER);

`the next line is where i am seeing my error`
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']"));
        password.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("abc123",Keys.ENTER);
 
        System.out.println("Test2 passed");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
  }```
````